# Vim airline branch not showing

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-fugitive, vim-airline

I've installed [bling/vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/) hoping I could have that cool branch name in my status bar.

[image]

I followed the instructions on airline's repo and installed [tpope/vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive).
But after downloading, installing, modifying and restarting vim, I just couldn't get the branch on the status bar. Instead I've got this:

[image]

I'm suspecting something was wrong with my `.vimrc` file?

Here is the part related to airline:

```
set ttimeoutlen=50
let g:airline_theme = 'powerlineish'
let g:airline#extensions#hunks#enabled=0
let g:airline#extensions#branch#enabled=1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
  let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif
let g:airline_symbols.space = "\ua0"
```

P.S. I'm new to vim, any advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What was your installation method? If it's Vundle, maybe you need to run :PluginInstall once more?

Comment: you need install a vim Plugin fugitive fugitive.vim: A Git wrapper so awesome, it should be illegal Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.vimrc` file looks fine. The problem is probably with plugins implementation, because there were some recent changes in airline initialization. Immediate solution to your problem would be to move back a little bit in git history of an airline plugin, as far as I know just the last commit causes problem, so you can just type in:

```
$ cd ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline
$ git checkout HEAD~1
```

If you want to stay up to date with the newest changes, monitor them on github, and run :PluginUpdate (for Vundle installation) or just `git pull origin master` to get newest features. If problem still exists, just go back a few commits or omit the one causing problems.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

My reputation isn't high enough to add a comment to quibix's solution hence this comment. 
The following commit is the last working airline commit that supports the fugitive status line addition. It does appear to break other plugins.

```
$git checkout e2a120869ba36da5d26df74fb23ef4052d55b6f0
```

**EDIT**

Actually **fugitive#head()** is on the master vim-fugitive branch. I figured out my problem was that fugitive was loaded after airline so airline_section_b was set to ''. Once I renamed the directory so that fugitive loaded before airline, HUNK/BRANCH started loading in the status line.